# How to map caps lock to arrow keys?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, xmodmap, xkb

I am trying to map Caps Lock to the Down arrow key and Caps Lock with a shift modifier to the up arrow key.

I've tried using xmodmap with the following input file:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keycode 66 = Down Up
```

Pressing caps lock does work for sending the down arrow key, but pressing caps lock + shift does not send Up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be a lot to the technical details to this solution. Feel free to jump to the **layout file** section if you do not care about the problem but only on the solution.

### xmodmap

Moving up and down via <kbd>CAPS</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CAPS</kbd> works on my system with the given `.Xmodmap` as expected.

You check whether your settings are actually in affect by calling

```
$ xmodmap -pk | grep ^\\s*66
     66     0xffe5 (Caps_Lock)  0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0xffe5 (Caps_Lock)
$ setxkbmap -layout us && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
$ xmodmap -pk | grep ^\\s*66
     66     0xff54 (Down)   0xff52 (Up)
```

### the LEVEL2 Modifier

There is another (real) problem to your question that comes next:

The LEVEL2 `<SHIFT>` modifier which is activated by pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button is there to visually mark characters in a text editor when moving through the lines with the arrow keys. If you assign `<UP>` <kbd>↑</kbd> to the second level of `<CAPS>`, what you are effectively doing is pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>. You have to deactivate the Shift modifier just for that scenario. Afaik you can not do this using xmodmap.

### redirecting LEVEL2 Modifier

The "real way" of modifying key maps is with [xkb](https://www.x.org/wiki/XKB/). I found the solution on [an old xorg mailing list](https://www.spinics.net/lists/xorg/msg35931.html). The LEVEL2 of <kbd>Caps</kbd> has to get redirected to the <kbd>↑</kbd>(`<UP>`) key (The Up-Key btw has only one level.) On X.org you can deactivating the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier during redirect with the built-in function `RedirectKey(key=<UP>, clearmods=Shift)`. clearmods "releases" the Shift modifier before the the key is actually "pressed".

### layout file

The simplest way to activate the behavior is to create a new layout file:

/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/capslockarrow

```
default partial xkb_symbols "basic" {

    include "de(basic)"
    include "shift(both_capslock_cancel)"

    key <CAPS> {
        type[Group1] = "TWO_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1] = [ Down, NoSymbol ],
        actions[Group1] = [ NoAction(), RedirectKey(key=<UP>, clearmods=Shift) ]
    };
 };
```

activate the new layout with

```
setxkbmap capslockarrow
```

### Notes on the layout file

- The new layout file derives from `de(basic)`. That is the layout for the **standard german keyboard**. You can add any other layout here like `us(basic)` or `us(euro)`. see `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` to get a glance of what is possible. The two letter code is the filename and in brackets is the respective `xkb_symbols` definition from the file.
- You would not have a caps key modifier anymore. Therefore I added a sort of replacement for <kbd>Caps</kbd>: `shift(both_capslock_cancel)` By pressing both <kbd>LSHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>RSHIFT</kbd> together, you can activate <kbd>CAPS Lock</kbd> and you release the Lock again with any other press of a <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.
- If anyone is wondering why I did not use a new type definition for that: I simply could not release the Shift modifier before the action of the Up Key was triggered. Releasing the Shift key though should be possible by explicitly calling `preserve[Shift] = None` in a spearated `xkb_types`.
- As stated in the comments below, Wayland will also rely on XKB but will not allow redirections.

Comment: wayland uses XKB (via `xkbcommon`, not the X11 library), so modified XKB options will work.  (at least if they're placed in the system XKB files.) `xmodmap` will not function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I figured I was sending shift + up. Now I can see I am when I highlight text in chrome. I guess the real question is how do I disable the level 2 switch, only for this scenario

Comment: I found the solution and updated my post.

Comment: nice solution, thanks.  i don't know if this will work in contexts like wayland that use `xkbcommon` -- [redirect actions are listed](https://xkbcommon.org/doc/current/md_doc_compat.html) among the current incompatibilities, though that could be remedied in the future.

Comment: as a side note, this xkb solution would be more elegant as an *option* instead of a full *layout*.

Comment: I agee regarding the option. I had it in a previous edit of this solution but you will have to edit existing files like base, base.lst and base.xml which will all be reverted on package upgrades. Or you build a sed script or use the developers tool for creating the xml file. Anyway it will be more complicated and there will be not much use for it since the option will not get merged upstream. It would be nice, I agree, but it’s probably a waste of time.

Comment: Could you put a warning in that you included the dutch keyboard and to replace it with the user's preferred?

Comment: @jared-beach done

Answer (score 0):

On linux, I strongly recommend [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd/). You can look at the example config which will help you to achieve your goal.
[kmonad](https://github.com/kmonad/kmonad) would be an alternative